# SQL - Left outer join, MINUS , INTERSECTION speed comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, database-performance

I am trying to implement SCD Type1 using PL/SQL

This is my source table

**SRC**

```
ID      NAME    PIN
101     ABC     250001
503     KLM     260001
981     PQR     260001
207     AKN     560
```

This is my target table

**TRGT**

```
ID      NAME    PIN
101     ABC     25001
981     PQR     26789
```

If I use Left outer join

```
select TRGT.ID AS TRID,
       SRC.ID AS SRID
  from SRC 
  left join TRGT on TRGT.ID = SRC.ID;
```

I will get this.

**OUTPUT**

```
TRID    SRID
101     101     
NULL    503
981     981
NULL    207
```

**Not much important just FYI**

In SCD type 1

- I need to insert all the SRID which have corresponding NULL TRID , as they are new records and are not present in TRID.
- I need to update all the SRID which have corresponding records present in TRID, as they are old records need to be updated.

**FYI ends**

I have written some logic and inserted 503,207 and updated 101,981.

Coming to Minus and Intersection operator.

To extract 503,207 (for insertion) I can use

```
SELECT ID FROM SRC 
MINUS
SELECT ID FROM TRGT
```

To extract 101,981(for update) I can use

```
SELECT ID FROM SRC
INTERSECT
SELECT ID FROM TRGT.
```

**AND NOW THE QUESTION**

For me implementing the whole SCD type1 is easy when I am using `MINUS`, `INTERSECT` as compared to 
Left outer Join.

But which will be faster, more efficient?

As I am going to deal with a large # of records in SRC and small #s in TRGT - at initial level.
but at later stages it would be other way around.

Thanks for your comments. Sorry for being verbose, I was trying my best to explain my state of mind.

Comment: Replaced the `plsql` tag with Oracle as this is plain SQL, no PL/SQL involved

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the MERGE statement? I believe it is actually designed for optimal performance in a case like yours.

Something like:

```
MERGE INTO trgt
USING src
ON (trgt.id = src.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET trgt.name = src.name, trgt.pin = src.pin
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (trgt.id, trgt.name, trgt.pin)
  VALUES (src.id, src.name, src. pin);
```

Comment: Thank You Jens & Frank for your reply and introducing me with Merge statement. But just out of curiosity i want to know what will be better option between Left outer join and Minus,Intersaction operator considering performance.(i read it that LOJ is better as MINUS make temporary table and delete row of 2nd table one by one hence takes alot of time)

Going forward i may have to write whole logic using PL/SQL,as after deciding on first update condition i need to compare PIN column again (SRC vs TRGT),if PIN is update then only i will update else i will skip the update.

Comment: can i use nested merge OR extra condition like
MERGE INTO trgt
USING src
ON (trgt.id = src.id) & (src.pin !=trgt.pin)

Comment: Yeah i think we can do that using where condition,
let me comeback with code.

Comment: i think this should work
"MERGE INTO trgt
USING src
ON (trgt.id = src.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET trgt.name = src.name, trgt.pin = src.pin
  where src.pin != trgt.pin
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (trgt.id, trgt.name, trgt.pin)
  VALUES (src.id, src.name, src. pin);"

Comment: I am happy that you could use the merge. As for LOJ vs. MINUS I have to admit that I dont know.